# Swift - Reading relatively complex array for UITableViewController

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, loops

I am struggling with the following:

I am trying to design and read in an array that holds the information for a UITableViewController.

The table view will have several sections, each section with a few cells, and each cell will have a name, and a on/off switch.

With the help of stackoverlfow I was able to get to this point below where I have most everything except the default position for the UISwitch.

```
import UIKit

class SettingsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var sections = ["Panels:": ["Radar", "ADIRs", "Transponder"], "Engine Type:": ["IAE", "CFM", "NEO"]]

    struct Objects {

        var sectionName: String!
        var sectionObjects: [String]!
    }

    var objectArray = [Objects]()

    let cellId = "cellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for (key, value) in sections {
            print("\(key) \(value)")
            objectArray.append(Objects(sectionName: key, sectionObjects: value))
        }

        navigationItem.title = "Settings"
        tableView.register(PanelCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        tableView.allowsSelection = false
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "< BACK", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.navigateBack))
    }

    func navigateBack() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objectArray[section].sectionObjects.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! PanelCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = objectArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]
        cell.panelSwitch.isOn = true 
        cell.settingsTableViewController = self
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return objectArray[section].sectionName
    }
}
```

... So in order to include the initial position of the UISwitch I have tried to design a different array like this:

```
var sections:[(sectionTitle: String, [(itemTitle: String, defaultValue: Bool)])] = [
    ("Panels", [("Radar",false),("ADIRs",false),("Transponder",false)]),
    ("Engine Type", [("IAE",false),("CFM",true),("NEO",false)])
]
```

I have modified the Objects struct as follows:

```
struct Object {

    var sectionName: String!
    var items: [(title: String, onOff: Bool)]!
}
```

However I am unable to figure out how to read all this into an array of Object(s).

```
var objectArray = [Object]()
var object = Object()

for index in sections {

   print("\(index)")
   object.sectionName = index[0].sectionTitle
}
```

The last line above gives me an error. If I try to access it like this it works:

```
print("\(sections[0].sectionTitle)")
print("\(sections[0].1[0].itemTitle)")
print("\(sections[0].1[0].defaultValue)")
print("\(sections[0].1[1].itemTitle)")
print("\(sections[0].1[1].defaultValue)")
print("\(sections[0].1[2].itemTitle)")
print("\(sections[0].1[2].defaultValue)")
```

So I have no idea how to read this array into objectArray properly. I also have the gut feeling that my whole approach to the problem is just wrong.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I update a little bit of your code to make it work:

```
typealias CellObject = (title: String, onOff: Bool)

class SettingsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var sections: [String: [CellObject]] = [
        "Panels:":
            [("Radar", true),
             ("ADIRs", false),
             ("Transponder", false)
        ],
        "Engine Type:": [
            ("IAE", true),
            ("CFM", false),
            ("NEO", false)
        ]
    ]

    struct Objects {

        var sectionName: String
        var sectionObjects: [CellObject]
    }

    var objectArray = [Objects]()

    let cellId = "cellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for (key, value) in sections {
            print("\(key) \(value.count)")
            objectArray.append(Objects(sectionName: key, sectionObjects: value))
        }

        navigationItem.title = "Settings"
        tableView.register(PanelCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        tableView.allowsSelection = false
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "< BACK", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.navigateBack))
    }

    func navigateBack() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return objectArray.count // don't use sections object anymore
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objectArray[section].sectionObjects.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! PanelCell
        let item = objectArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLabel.text = item.title
        cell.panelSwitch.isOn = item.onOff
        // cell.settingsTableViewController = self // you should not pass controller to the cell
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return objectArray[section].sectionName
    }
}
```

**EDITED**

For avoiding the dictionary ordering uncertain issue, the data structure can be (as JSON format):

```
[
  {
    "title": "Panels",
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "Radar",
        "selected": true
      },
      {
        "name": "ADIRs",
        "selected": false
      },
      {
        "name": "Transponder",
        "selected": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Engine Type",
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "IAE",
        "selected": true
      },
      {
        "name": "CFM",
        "selected": false
      },
      {
        "name": "NEO",
        "selected": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The data class can be defined as:

```
class Data {
    var title: String?
    var items: [Detail]?
}

class Detail {
    var name: String?
    var selected: Bool?
}
```

Then your array will be type of `var objectArray = [Data]()`. Convert the JSON string to `[[String: Any]]` and set to objectArray (Google or search this site for how to convert JSON string to array).

If the data must return dictionary, you need to discuss with your client or team mates what's the best way to order the dictionary keys to make sure the data is present as expected.

Comment: To remind: because your are using dictionary to covert to an array, the ordering in objectArray might be uncertain.

Comment: bubuxu! This works great! THANK YOU!!! Well above my pay grade. In order to ensure ordering, what other collection type should I use instead of dictionaries?

Comment: @user1269290 Please see the updated answer for explaining how to avoid the uncertain dictionary.

Comment: Thank you! I am using JSON elsewhere so this makes sense to me.